# Dropdown with LIKE operator react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a table that implements [react-bootstrap-table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html). They provide a custom way of doing external filter (out of the column header). In my table, the first column is a combination of data that I pass a string with `@` as separator and the format them with the formatter function as follow:

This is my column definition:

```
  let projectFilter;
   columns = [{
        dataField: 'project',
        text: 'Project',
        filter: textFilter({
          options: fpsoOptions,
          getFilter(filter){
            projectFilter = filter;
          },
          style: { display: 'none' }
        }),
        sort: true,
        formatter: this.projectFormatter,
        headerStyle: (col, idx) => {
          return smHeaderStyle;
        },
      }, [..]
```

And this is the `projectFormatter` function:

```
projectFormatter = (cell, row) => {
    const values = cell.split('|');
    const fpsos = values[0].split('@');
    return (
      <div>
        {fpsos.map((pu, idx) => {
          const identity = pu.split(';')[0];
          const id = pu.split(';')[1];
          const separator = idx !== fpsos.length - 1 ? ", " : '';
          return (
            <Link to={`/view/${id}/fpso`}>{identity}{separator}</Link>
          )
        })}
        <br/>
        <span><b>{ values[1] }</b></span><br/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The filtering works fine when it is a text input filter. Now, I'm trying to do a custom select filter with a LIKE operator behaviour, which the selected value in the dropdown (fpso list) would be filtered as a substring of this column.

This is my `onChange` function that triggers the table filter, as shown in the documentation [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Column%20Filter&selectedStory=Programmatically%20Select%20Filter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). But I'm not sure how to get the `like` behaviour.

```
 const onChangeFilter = (e) => {
        projectFilter(e.target.value)
    }
```

I appreciate any clue/help. Thanks in advance